# Export datatable to CSV in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, datatable

I have a datatable that is used to populate a gridview as well as being used to download into a csv. The gridview is displayed and then the user has an option of downloading as a csv.

However, when the gridview is downloaded some of the cells are left empty in the csv in the last row. When I run it through debug mode and view the datatable there are no empty cells.

Any ideas what is causing this or how to fix it?

Following is the code is used for downloading CSV.

```
protected void down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  String name = Request.QueryString["name"]; 
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
  core.Data.CSVDataWriter c = new CSVDataWriter(); 
  c.Export(ms, datasource); Response.Clear(); 
  Response.ContentType = "text/csv"; 
  Response.AddHeader
  (
    "Content-Disposition"
   , "attachment; filename=" + name + ".csv"
  ); 
  Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray()); 
  Response.Flush(); 
  Response.Close(); 
  Response.End(); 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `DataSource` of the `GridView` instead of the `GridView` itself? The original source could already be outdated. So you could load the source again in the export-event. That is also better because the grid contains only text whereas the source contains the original type (f.e. `DateTime`) and you can decide how you want to export it.

Comment: That's what I am doing already.  That's why I can't understand why it is leaving empty cells, sometimes it's one cell missing or other times it can be up to 4 cells missing.

Comment: I don't understand your question anymore. Do you have problems to export the grid or does the grid show empty cells after you've exported it?

Comment: No the datatable is used to populate the gridview and then there is a button to allow the user to download the gridview as a CSV.  When downloading as a CSV it is the datasource of the datatable that is used.  However some times when you download the gridview as a CSV there are cells missing.

Comment: It's still not clear, the `DataTable` is the `DataSource` of the `GridView`. Now you export the source of the `DataTable` (i assume a database query). How are the empty gridview cells related to this issue at all? Or in other words, how is the export related at all if the empty cells are the issue? Maybe it'll help if you show some code.

Comment: There are no empty gridview cells, it's cells in the CSV that are empty even though it is displaying the same data that is shown in the gridview where there are no empty cells.

Comment: Then show us the relevant code, maybe we can fix it.

Comment: In your routine that creates the `CSV` (_comma_ separated values), check if you handle comma `,` in the source data (if any), and/or enclose the source data that has the comma (if any) in quotes....Hth...